# Materialize get modal trigger element

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

How do I get the element that triggered a Materialize Modal?

Given this code :

```
<a class="trigger-modal" href="#modal1" data-id="1">Item 1</a>
<a class="trigger-modal" href="#modal1" data-id="2">Item 2</a>
<a class="trigger-modal" href="#modal1" data-id="3">Item 3</a>

<div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Edit Model</h4>
    <form> ... </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
    dismissible: false,
    ready() { console.log('Ready', this, arguments); },
    complete() { console.log('Closed', this, arguments); }
  });
});
</script>
```

How can I get which anchor element triggered the modal? Both `ready` and `complete` only have `this` set to the modal options, and `arguments` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

use JavaScript `getElementsByTagName` to get all the anchors; `getElementsByClassName` would also work if the anchors share a class.  Add `href="javascript:void(0)"` to your anchors.

Then in your click handler, use console.log(event.target) or (e.target)

```
var doc = document;
var anchors = doc.getElementsByTagName('a');

if(anchors){
  for (var i = 0; i < providers.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
      console.log(event.target);
      console.log(event.target.id);
      console.log(event.target.className);
      console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
    });
  }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Materialize Modal docs it doesn't seem that something else passed into ready or complete callback however you can get away by adding code to record last clicked anchor.

Can be done by adding:

```
 onclick="window.lastAnchorClicked = this;"
```

to your anchors. And then use `window.lastAnchorClicked` to access last clicked anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my method:

```
$('.modal').modal({
ready: function(modal, trigger) { // Callback for Modal open. Modal and trigger parameters available.

   console.log(trigger.prevObject[0].id);

  },
});
```

This will print the id of the object that triggered the modal to show.

I hope anyone who needs this finds this useful!